# Можно ли конвертировать "std::function<int(int)>" в "typedef int (*MyFunction) (int k);"

Tags: c++, замыкания, преобразование-типов

**Доброго времени суток. Подскажите есть ли какой нибудь способ осуществить перевод из типа `"std::function<int(int)>"` в тип `"int (*MyFunction) (int k);`"**

У меня есть функция

```
void someFnc(MyFunction collbackFn);
```

в которую я пытаюсь передать функцию создаваемую с помощью замыкания:

```
auto getFn(int ll)
{
return [=](int k)
    {
      std::cout<<(k+ll)<<"\n"; // тут какие то действия
      return k+ll;
    };   
}

someFnc(getFn(12));
```

Однако у меня не как не получается конвертировать тип функции который я получаю на выходе из замыкания, в требуемый. Я не могу отредактировать код функции в которую передаю замыкание `void someFnc(MyFunction collbackFn);`, так как она не мною была написана. И мне нужно замыкание либо что то в этом роде, для того что бы сгенерировать функцию с занесенным параметром внутри (зафиксированным), так как он (параметр) будет передаваться лишь единожды и не будет не где сохраняться.

Для большей конкретики, по этой ссылке [ссылке](http://cpp.sh/4ngsq) (адрес: http://cpp.sh/4ngsq), в веб среде С++ я маленький пример накидал, которых иллюстрирует ту задачу которую я не как не могу решить.

Подскажите как можно было бы решить данный вопрос ?

Comment: Именно из-за того, что вам нужно замыкание, этого сделать нельзя.

Comment: Это то я уже понял. Но как можно обойти подобное ? можно ли что то другое использовать как вариант ? я уже который день вожусь и не пойму если честно как реализовать это.

Comment: А при чем тут `std::function<int(int)>`? Вы уверены, что в ту функцию, в которую вы передаете ваш колбек нельзя передать какой-нибудь пользовательский параметр?

Comment: да уверен. 
просто моя функция возвращающая замыкание нормально работает с `std::function<int(int)>`, но не хочет работать с `MyFunction`

по ссылке в вопросе я пример привел

Comment: Ну тогда вариантов только два: сохранять `ll` в глобальную переменную и делать калбек обычной функцией - подойдет, если он в любой момент существует только один; либо генерировать тело колбека в рантайме, встраивая в него требуемое значение `ll`.

Comment: Благодарю за совет. Мне думаю второе подойдет, однако не совсем пойму как бы это реализовать ? Можно ли где нибудь пример подобного посмотреть?

Comment: Но вот был [такого рода вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14825986/generating-functions-at-runtime-in-c).

Comment: Если ваши инты были известны на этапе компиляции(как в примере), можно было бы протащить их через шаблоны

Comment: На этапе компиляции к сожалению не получится, я эти параметры из вне задавать буду

Comment: Простите, а где здесь `std::function<int(int)>`? Я не вижу ни в тексте вопроса, ни в коде ни малейшего намека на использование `std::function`. Учитывая, что `std::function` в вопросе никак не участвует, первая часть вопроса является дубликатом https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/768045/%D0%9B%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B1%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B5/768051

Comment: Благодарю всех откликнувшихся за советы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант со статическими переменными (можно заменить static на thread_local, но как это скажется на производительности мне неизвестно):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include<functional>

template<class Fn>
struct static_capture_impl;

template<class R, class... Args>
struct static_capture_impl<R(Args...)>{
    using ret_value_t = R(*)(Args...);

    template<class Fn>
    ret_value_t  operator()(Fn fn) const{
       static auto state = std::move(fn);  
       return [](Args... args)->R{ 
          return state(args...);
       };
    }
};

// Это чтобы обрабатывались и указатели на функции
template<class R, class... Args>
struct static_capture_impl<R(*)(Args...)>: public static_capture_impl<R(Args...)> {};


template<class Ret, class Fn>
auto static_capture(Fn fn){
    return static_capture_impl<Ret>{}(std::move(fn));
}

/// example

using call_back_t = int(*)(int k);

int main() {
  int localVar = 5;
  call_back_t fn = static_capture<call_back_t>([localVar](int num) {  
    std::cout << localVar<<std::endl;
    std::cout << num <<std::endl;
    return num + localVar;
  });

  fn(15);
}
```

Если api позволяет передавать не только указатель на функцию, но и указатель на данные (`void*`) - можно конвертировать лямбду в `void*`, и передавать c-функцию, которая распаковывает `void*` обратно в лямбду (тут опять нужны шаблоны).

Comment: Благодарю, поразбираюсь с вашим вариантом, возможно то что нужно.