# Лямбда, и передача значений в нее

Tags: c++, c++14

Узнал что в `WNDCLASS` можно передать лямбду в качестве `lpfnWndProc`, и да, передать ее можно. Тут же подумалось мне что можно передать какие-то локальные значения в лямбду, но не тут то было. Простая лямбда, да, а вот с передачей значений по ссылке нет. Можно как то исправить ситуацию?

`не существует подходящей функции преобразования из "lambda []LPARAM (HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)->LPARAM" в "WNDPROC"`

```
// Так пожалуйста
wc.lpfnWndProc = [](HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM) -> LRESULT {};

// Так нельзя.
wc.lpfnWndProc = [&](HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM) -> LRESULT {};
```

Comment: Так ведь одно дело - "чистая" лямбда, и другое - хранящая дополнительную информацию - она же реализуется как объект класса с полями и оператором `()`. Как минимум, такая лямбда получает еще и `this` свое реализации, и уже никак не соответствует требуемому типу.

Comment: Все нужные данные для оконной процедуры следует передавать либо через само окно - вызывая `SetWindowLongPtr` / `GetWindowLongPtr` c параметром `GWLP_USERDATA`, либо генерируя тело оконной процедуры в рантайме.

Comment: @VTT: Так можно делать если подключаемые библиотеки не используют `GWLP_USERDATA`, в моем случае не подходит :)

Comment: Как вариант можно еще держать `map<HWND, user_data>`.

Comment: @VTT: Так и подумал, пытаюсь реализовать

Comment: [Связанный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/562106/3380)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нельзя. В общем случае средств closure, которые в итоге формируют "обычный" указатель на функцию в языке нет. Лямбда тут не поможет - как только появился не пустой capture, лямбду больше уже нельзя преобразовать в обычный указатель на функцию.